# Typescript: declare class implementing interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There’s a typed module – `'markdown-it'` – defining an interface that describes a class living in another (untyped) module – `'markdown-it/lib/token'`

I would like to define typings for the latter, for which I created a `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'markdown-it/lib/token' {
    import * as MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it'

    class Token implements MarkdownIt.Token {}
    export = Token
}
```

Sadly, Typescript complains that `Token` doesn’t implement `MarkdownIt.Token`.

Optimally, I’d like to tell Typescript “the class and interface are identical”. But even if this isn’t possible, I can’t even copy the definition, as

> Class `Token` incorrectly implements interface `markdownit.Token`.
>   Type `Token` provides no match for the signature `new (type: string, tag: string, nesting: number): Token`

no matter if I do

```
class Token implements MarkdownIt.Token {
    new (type: string, tag: string, nesting: number): Token
    // or
    new (type: string, tag: string, nesting: number): Token
    // or
    constructor(type: string, tag: string, nesting: number)
...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to merge the class declaration with an interface declaration that extends the original interface:

```
declare module 'markdown-it/lib/token' {
    import * as MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it'

    interface Token extends MarkdownIt.Token {}
    class Token {}
    export = Token
}
```

When you manually copied the interface methods, you found what appears to be a mistake in the original interface declaration, which won't stop the above technique from working but is nevertheless wrong:

```
interface Token {
    new (type: string, tag: string, nesting: number): Token;
    // ...
}
```

This is saying that a `Token` instance can be used with the `new` operator to create another `Token` instance, e.g.:

```
import Token = require("markdown-it/lib/token");
let a = new Token(...);
let b = new a(...);
```

That would be highly unusual design and I see no indication in the JavaScript implementation that it is actually supported.  Please [file an issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues) to have the construct signature removed.  Or if you plan to contribute your enhancement to DefinitelyTyped, you could just make the change in the same pull request.

Comment: Yes, the `new` declaration is indeed in the original (no constructor though). Thank you, this worked!